# Core Audio specify which audio track to decode

Tags: c++, audio, core-audio

I am able to successfully get the decoded PCM data of an audio file using Core Audio API. Below is the **reduced** code that shows how do I do that:

```
CFStringRef urlStr = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "file.m4a", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFURLRef urlRef = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, urlStr, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);    

ExtAudioFileOpenURL(urlRef, &m_audioFile);

bzero(&m_outputFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
m_outputFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
m_outputFormat.mSampleRate = m_inputFormat.mSampleRate;
m_outputFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
m_outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = m_inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
m_outputFormat.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(short) * m_outputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
m_outputFormat.mBitsPerChannel = sizeof(short) * 8;
m_outputFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
m_outputFormat.mBytesPerPacket = m_outputFormat.mBytesPerFrame * m_outputFormat.mFramesPerPacket;


ExtAudioFileSetProperty(m_audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(m_outputFormat), &m_outputFormat)

short* transformData = new short[sampleCount];    

AudioBufferList fillBufList;
fillBufList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
fillBufList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = channels;
fillBufList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = m_sampleCount * sizeof(short);
fillBufList.mBuffers[0].mData = (void*)(&transformData[0]);

ExtAudioFileRead(m_audioFile, &m_frameCount, &fillBufList);
```

I am interested in ***how can I specify*** the audio track I want to decode (suppose that media file contains more than one)?

Answer (score -1):

One method is to decode all tracks and then extract (copy) the desired track data (every other sample for interleaved stereo, etc.) into another buffer, array, or file.  Compared to the decode time, the extra copy time is insignificant.

Comment: And how to set to decode all tracks?
Also, I am interesting in getting metadata of all audio tracks (i.e bitrate, sample rate, number of channels, etc.). How do I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is the comment section, not the new question section.